# python pandas exploding multiple varying length dataframe columns containing arrays

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains 1 single array per column that i need to explode to multiple rows per column. the arrays are nested (twice) and varying length (6-12 arrays contained in each)
I'm trying to either;

- explode the top level of each nested array or
- explode everything and have a multi-index

example data:
[image]

I have tried varying methods found here on SO using the built in explode function, haven't been able to produce anything that

Comment: Please provide some sample data in text and the expected output layout.

Answer (score 0):

My example df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"k_6_cluster":[[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]],"k_7_cluster":[[[10,20,30],[40,50,60],[70,80,90]],[[10,20,30],[40,50,60],[70,80,90]]]

print(df)


               k_6_cluster                        k_7_cluster
    0   [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]   [[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60], [70, 80, 90]]
    1   [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]   [[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60], [70, 80, 90]]
```

Following lines of code will explode the top level of each nested array

```
list_cols = df.columns
exploded = [df[col].explode() for col in list_cols]
out_df = pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(list_cols, exploded)))

print(out_df)

        k_6_cluster  k_7_cluster
    0   [1, 2, 3]   [10, 20, 30]
    0   [4, 5, 6]   [40, 50, 60]
    0   [7, 8, 9]   [70, 80, 90]
    1   [1, 2, 3]   [10, 20, 30]
    1   [4, 5, 6]   [40, 50, 60]
    1   [7, 8, 9]   [70, 80, 90]
```

Comment: hi, firstly thank you. but this doesnt seem to work, error: ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis. could this be because the arrays are a different size?

Comment: Did you try with my example df?

Comment: yes, which works. but all of the arrays are the same size. if you were to add a 4th list into the k_7_cluster array as [100,110,120] then it fails.